# Writing an SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to Select columns from Table 1 with a Row Filter, Select columns from Table 2 and join.

This works but it's a bit verbose. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ((SELECT JOB_NUM, ITEM_NUMBER, DATE_COMPLETED, QTY_COMPLETED, STD_USAGE, ACTUAL_USAGE FROM JOB_ROUTERS WHERE RESOURCE_CODE == "TDWELD") AS JOBS
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ITEM, DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTE) as item
  ON JOBS.ITEM_NUMBER == ITEM.ITEM)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do the deep abstraction for the `Select *`. You can simply reference the columns you want and include them in the result...

```
SELECT JOB_NUM,
       ITEM_NUMBER,
       DATE_COMPLETED,
       QTY_COMPLETED,
       STD_USAGE,
       ACTUAL_USAGE,
       ITEM,
       DESCRIPTION
FROM JOB_ROUTERS
LEFT JOIN ITEM_ATTRIBUTE
       ON JOBS.ITEM_NUMBER == ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.ITEM
WHERE RESOURCE_CODE == "TDWELD"
```